# The id of datelist which is inside another datalist in not accessible in .cs file

Tags: c#, datalist

I have a datalist control which is inside another datalist.I need to access the inside one datalist id in the .cs file.

Here is my two datalists.

```
<asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" DataKeyField="sid" ItemStyle-CssClass="lft_c_down"  runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="wholeC">
        <div class="ctop">
        <div class="lft_l">
        <div class="lft_l_top">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath")%>' Height="245px" Width="297px" />
        <br/>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="lft_r">

        <asp:Label ID="lbl_sid" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"sid") %>' runat="server" Visible="false" />
        <b class="products" >Product Name:</b>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ipath") %>' runat="server" />
        <br/>
        <b class="products">Brand:</b>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"brand") %>' runat="server" />
        <br/>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cdown">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_cmt" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="500px" placeholder="comment.."  />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Comment" backcolor="black" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Consolas" Font-Overline="False" 
        ForeColor="White" Height="34px" Width="108px" OnClick="cmt_Click" />


    <asp:DataList ID = "dl_cmt" runat="server">
        <ItemStyle CssClass="coment" />
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblcmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ecomment")%>' />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" style=" color:brown; font-family:Cursive; font-size:x-small; " runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("my_date","on {0}") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_showMore" runat="server">Show More</asp:LinkButton>--%>
        </div>
        </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Now here is the .cs file where i want to access the datalist if of datalist `dl_cmt`.And this is what i have tried.

```
 public void show_comment()
{

    string str = gstr;
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 4 * from comment where sid='" + str + "' order by my_date desc", sq.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);



    DataList dl = (DataList)FindControl("dl_cmt");
    dl.DataSource = ds;
    dl.DataBind();

}
```

**Edit**

I have this button click event where i want to call the `showcomment`.

```
 protected void cmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    DataListItem dli = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    TextBox tx = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("tb_cmt");
    Label lb = (Label)dli.FindControl("lbl_sid");
    string userid = Session["userid"].ToString();

    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into comment(ecomment,sid,my_date,regid_cmt) values(@myecomment,@mysid,@mydate,@reg_id)", sq.con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myecomment", tx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mysid", lb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm, MMM  dd, yyyy"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_id", userid);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sq.con.Dispose();
    sq.con.Close();
    tx.Text = "";

    //show_comment();



}
```

**EDIT:**

This is how the gstr is getting its value.

```
public partial class loggedin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string gstr;
sql_con sq = new sql_con();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string st = Session["email"].ToString();
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        hfm mymaster = (hfm)Page.Master;
        lcont lc = mymaster.getlcont();
        lc.myevent += delegate(string st2)
        {
            string str = st2;
            gstr = str;
            showdata();
            bind_menuitem();
            bindratingService();
            bindrating();
            show_comment();
            bindslide();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it on something like ItemDataBound or ItemCreated as the inner DataList is an item within the outer list:

```
protected void mydatalist_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        DataList dl = e.Item.FindControl("dl_cmt") as DataList;

        string str = gstr;
        sq.connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 4 * from comment where sid='" + str + "' order by my_date desc", sq.con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        dl.DataSource = ds;
        dl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ASP.NET code would need to include the event such as:

```
OnItemDataBound="mydatalist_ItemDataBound"
```

***UPDATE***

To do this within a button click event or separate method you should be able to do this:

```
protected void show_comment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataListItem item in mydatalist.Items)
    {
        int index = item.itemindex;

        DataList dl = (DataList) mydatalist.Items[index].FindControl("dl_cmt");

        string str = gstr;
        sq.connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 4 * from comment where sid='" + str + "' order by my_date desc", sq.con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        dl.DataSource = ds;
        dl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

***UPDATE 2***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(gstr)) Setgstr();
}

private void Setgstr()
{
    //Your code to set gstr
}
```

***UPDATE 3***

You could also use Session to store the variable:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["gstr"] = //Your code to set gstr
}
```

Access it like this:

```
string str = Session["gstr"].ToString();
```

Comment: can you tell me how to call this function `mydatalist_ItemDataBound` in another function.The thing is i want to call this function on button click event `cmt_Click`.

Comment: @user35 - you should be able to. Just do as above, but rather than using the DataLiistItemEventArgs e to access your inner list, access your list by DataList dl = (DataList)mydatalist.item.FindControl("dl_cmt");

Comment: `DataList dl = (DataList)mydatalist.item.FindControl("dl_cmt");` dosent work..i mean `FindControl()` is not recognized

Comment: First thing the `dl` is shown null and second thing it goes to infinite loop why?

Comment: @user35 - is the dl showing as null within your show_comment() method or are you saying it's null within the ItemDataBound() method?

Comment: Its null within the `itemdatabound`

Comment: @user35 - so you've stepped through the code in debug and after DataBind() dl is still null? If so, is ds getting filled? I've added an update for something that should work for a separate method (not on ItemDataBound or ItemCreated etc.). However, this assumes you're able to fill dl.

Comment: And how do i call this function `showcomment` inside other function.I need to call this function after a button click event.

Comment: I'm simply using your example method of show_comment(). If you only want to do it on a button click then stick it within the button click. Alternatively, you would simply call it by putting 'show_coment();' in your button click method.

Comment: NO i want to do it as you have mentioned..but i also need to call the function `showcomment` in the buttonclick event.I cannot directly use showcomment() because it says `no overload for menthd showcomment takes 0 argument`.So how do i call this function from a button click event?

Comment: @user35 - so you want to call this twice? Once on ItemDataBound (or ItemCreated) and another when a button is clicked?

Comment: Now i want to call this function on button click only.Actually what i am trying to acheieve is to show the comments immediately after the comment is inserted by clicking the button.If i am able to call the function `showcoment` in button click i would be able to show the comment immediately..plz check the edit

Comment: @user35 -  then you should be able to simply use the show_comment() method in my update but assign this to the button click event.

Comment: button click event is already used to insert data...i need this function `showcomment()` seperate as you have provide but then i need to call this function in the last line of button click event `cmt_click`.I have provided this event in the edit..please check

Comment: @user35 - If you do it like you've put in your edit is there where dl is null and it's doing an infinite loop?

Comment: But first i need to call the `show_comment` function first in the button click event.HOw to do that? I simply cant call `Showcomment` as there are arguments in the function as `show_comment(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @user35 - If you want to call it within cmt_click() then simply include the line you have commented out (show_comment();) wherever you need it (at the top if that's where you want). Forgot to say, you can remove object sender, EventArgs e from show_comment()

Comment: @user35 - alternatively to the above just call it by typing show_comment(sender, e);

Comment: Wow that was great.. just one more thing in the code you can see `string str = gstr`.The gstr is a global variable which is accessible anywhere but it is not accessible inside `show_comment()`. why?

Comment: @user35 - how / where exactly is gstr defined?

Comment: inside class and outside and above page_load event as `public partial class loggedin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string gstr;`

Comment: @user35 - if your declaring it like public string gstr = "my string"; within the same class as your show_comment method this should be available. Any chance of the code showing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59170/discussion-between-user35-and-sr28).

Comment: @user35 - you're not assigning anything to gstr, so when you try and use it there's nothing to assign to string str. If it was a local variable you'd be warned of this with "Use of unassigned local variable."